# NHibernate manually control fetching

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fetch

I am using NHibernate and I want to control fetching related entities manually.

Here is my sample entity

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The behvaiour I expect is as follows:

```
session.Query<Post>().ToList();
```

After this kind of query I want `Post` entities to have:

1. Primitive properties are set
2. `User` property is not null but only have Id property set.
3. `Likes` and `Tags` are null or empty collection

-

```
session.Query<Post>()
    .Fetch(p => p.User)
    .Fetch(p => p.Tags)
    .ToList();
```

And after this kind of query I want `Post` entities to have:

1. Primitive properties are set
2. `User` property is not null and properties are set.
3. `Tags` is not null and all items have all properties set
4. `Likes` is null or empty collection

Basically what I want from NHibernate is, not to fetch any related entities unless I ask for it to fetch and not cause an NHibernate specific exception (LazyInitialization etc.) when I try to access not fetched properties. The behaviour I expect is not lazy nor eager.

Before "what have you tried" comments, I tried almost all combinations with `LazyLoad()`, `Not`, `Fetch` etc. in Fluent NHibernate mapping configuration along with both statless and stateful sessions.

Comment: Are you working with session closed context, or why you get lazy initialization exception?

Comment: I got lazy initialization exception when I use stateless session (session opened). I understand that it is how NHibernate works. I am just trying to find a configuration that will make NHibernate work according to my expectations.

Comment: Why you get an exception to an initialized properties?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I get lazy initialization exception when I do not call `Fetch(p => p.Likes)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out how to deal with uninitialized instances without validate before call a reference:

```
NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(entityOrCollection)
```

And / or

```
NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(obj, "propertyName")
```

Comment: I would avoid manual fetching. I would prefer to create Projections, and batch-fetching. But this answer is the best among the other solutions...

Comment: If he needs his domain entities this can be the answer, but im agree with you, using projections with DTOs is easier and can gain performance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to setting the other collections to null as soon as you loaded your collection,

```
var list = session.Query<Post>()
    .Fetch(p => p.User)
    .Fetch(p => p.Tags)
    .ToList();
list.ForEach(i => i.Likes = null);
```

But you should not persist them (since you are using a stateless session I don't believe you intend to persist them anyway).