# Can you control fetching behaviour in Hibernate using the criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I know you can control fetching behaviour using [@javax.persistence.FetchType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html), however **can you control the fetching programmatically from within a JPA Criteria query?** Basically I can tell from the query what part of the application is likely calling and what part of the model will (most likely) be needed.

I couldn't find an answer in any of the tutorials but these old questions:

- [NHibernate manually control fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826248/nhibernate-manually-control-fetching) which is about NHibernate and has non-answers
- [How do you programmatically turn off eager fetching with hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372704/how-do-you-programmatically-turn-off-eager-fetching-with-hibernate) which doesn't mention the criteria API, and is so ancient as not to make this question an automatic duplicate, however I suspect [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372725/254477) may still be the current situation.
- [JPA & Criteria API - Select only specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618489/jpa-criteria-api-select-only-specific-columns) which is about returning tuples and not the model itself

---

**tl;dr:** can you control the fetching programmatically from within a JPA Criteria query?

Comment: you mean, like an EntityGraph? which applies to JPQL or Criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entity graphs for this (which works with JPQL and Criteria API).

Example:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.withRoles", attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("roles") // fetch "roles" eager
})
@NamedQuery(name = "User.byName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name")
public class User {
    /* ... */

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany // fetch lazy by default
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", /* ... */)
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

public User getUser(String name, boolean withRoles) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.byName", User.class);
    if (withRoles) {
        EntityGraph<User> loadGraph = (EntityGraph<User>) entityManager.createEntityGraph("User.withRoles");
        query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", loadGraph);
    }

    try {
        return query.setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can also use a fetch graph to exclude fields from being fetched.

Comment: @Neil exactly. Didn't see your comment at the time. :)